# resetting windows 10 thumbnails to work in July 2021 on a HP computer?

Tags: photo-editing, workflow

How to get the thumbnails reset on windows 10 forever so that I can see the photos in explorer?

What is the physics of thumbnails, and what gives with the file explorer attributes anyway?

What nerdy way to do things in Windows 10, is this a common problem, that thumbnails on pics on Onedrive, or google drive, or amazon drive do not work, beside the resident files on a picture file labeled as Raw, or jpeg do not show a thumbnail, even if Windows has a 10 and its updated monthly if not weekly what is the reseting of thumbnails like turning off a computer has to do with this traditional method to upload photos if they can be shown, hum, this is humbug, and insane, why this problematic error??

Is the professional world aware of the problem, and there is no fix, or is it to complex in file formats that every computer picture fails to register a photo thumbnail for another reason, please explain in laymens terms only. Brief concise and clearly, in High school grammer if that is okay. Most helpful, if you dont have a fix but can explain the problem holistically.  Thanks, a service provider here at this forum.

Comment: Thumbnails display fine on my computer running Windows 10. Without giving us more details about what is happening when you try to view thumbnails on your machine, we can't help you.

Comment: If you are only experiencing this issue with cloud based images, I'd look first at your internet service provider to see if they are intentionally preventing those preview images from transmitting/loading. This could very well have nothing to do with what OS your machine is running.